# How to get divs inside a main div to transition with it(and have a different transition)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a project where I have a main div that appears when I click a button. However, when that fades in, the other divs inside don't. Also, I wanted it to kind of scroll in instead of fade in.

Here is my whole code, Excuse me not snipping it, I'm new to this

I have a gif attatched for how I want the animation to be. I dont mind if there is a border showing or not, but i want everything inside the box in my code to move with the big one.[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Daily Homework</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:rgb(104, 200, 255);">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function expandContract() {
        const el = document.getElementById("inputLabel")
        el.classList.toggle('expanded')
        el.classList.toggle('collapsed')
      }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

      @font-face {
          font-family: "ArialRound";
          src: url('static/ArialRound.ttf') format("truetype");
      }

      h1 { 
          font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
      }

      #rcorners {
        border-radius: 15px;
        background-color: #00F3FF;
        border: 5px solid #0023FF;
        width: 350px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #a {
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #input {
        background-color: #afd3ff;
      }

      #inputButton {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b9d7ff;
        border: 6px solid #edefff;
        width: 450px;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #ela {
        background-color: #ee98ff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ff00f2;
      }

      #math {
        background-color: rgb(255, 92, 114);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ff0000;
      }

      #science {
        background-color: rgb(130, 255, 172);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #02df0d;
      }

      #socialStudies {
        background-color: rgb(255, 254, 183);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #eeff00;
      }

      #band {
        background-color: rgb(255, 133, 249);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #9900ff;
      }

      #inputLabel {
        margin-top: -100%;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #edefff;
      }

      #inputLabel.expanded {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b9d7ff;
        border: 6px solid #edefff;
        width: 450px;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: all 1s;
      }

      #center {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #expandContainer {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

    </style>


    <h2 id="a">{{ var1 }} Entries</h2>
    <h1 id="rcorners">Daily Homework</h1><br><br>
    <div id="center">

      <button id="inputButton" onclick="expandContract()">

        <h3>Click Here To Add New Entry</h3>
  
      </button>

    </div>

    <br>


    <div id="expandContainer">
      <div id="inputLabel" class="expanded">

        <div id="ela" class="expanded">
          <h4>ELA:</h4>
          <textarea id="input" name="ela" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="math">
          <h4>Math:</h4>
          <textarea id="input" name="math" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="science">
          <h4>Science:</h4>
          <textarea id="input" name="science" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="socialStudies">
          <h4>Social Studies:</h4>
          <textarea id="input" name="socialStudies" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="band">
          <h4>Band:</h4>
          <textarea id="input" name="band" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a sliding effect instead of a fading effect, and for all the child divs to move with the parent #inputLabel div.

First, let's set the initial state of the #inputLabel to be "hidden" and add a class for this.

For the sliding animation, we'll be using CSS transform property

```css
/* Initial state: hidden */
#inputLabel {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: transform 1s;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

/* When expanded */
#inputLabel.expanded {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```js
function expandContract() {
    const el = document.getElementById("inputLabel");
    el.classList.toggle('expanded');
}
```

With this code, when the #inputLabel div has the expanded class, it will be in its visible state, sliding down. When the expanded class is removed, it will slide up and be hidden.

Now, when you click the button, the #inputLabel div and all of its children will slide in from the top.